# android端末用アプリで通信状態が正常に取得できない

Tags: javascript, android, monaca, cordova

monacaを使用してアプリ開発をしています。
現在タブレット端末にて、一時的に圏外になりその後復帰した際にネットワーク情報を取得しても[none]のままになっていて内部的には通信エラーとして処理されてしまいます。
navigator.connection.type !== Connection.NONE = falseになる？

手動でモバイルデータのON/OFFを切り替えると正常に戻るようなのですが原因がわからない状態です。

一番は正常なネットワーク情報が取得できれば良いのですが、最悪はモバイルデータのon/offが可能であれば試してみたいです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: そのネットワークというのはWiFiですか、それともDocomoなどの回線ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。将来的にはwifiも想定していますが、現時点ではdocomoの回線(モバイルデータ通信)になります。

Comment: 趣旨が違うようですがこんな記事があります。[アプリユーザー端末のネットワーク接続が不安定な状況を把握する方法](https://teratail.com/questions/268478)